# W-4 allowances for H-1B resident alien with non working H-4 spouse

Tags: united-states, income-tax, withholding, form-w-4

After more than 183 days within the US territory, I would like to change my W-4 to fit my current situation: working in the US with a H-1B visa, that is, resident alien, and my spouse has the H-4, lives here with me in the US and does not work (she is my dependant). No children.

Can anyone explain how many allowances can I clain and what should I put on my W-4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the worksheet, then:

- 1 for yourself
- 1 since You are married, have only one job, and your spouse does not work
- 1 for your spouse

for a total of 3.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you please specify how can I know that this is true? is the any website I can use to get that number?

Comment: @DídacPérezParera: I'm not sure what you mean. All this is from the worksheet on the front of the W-4 form.